# Minimization of the regex

Tags: python, regex, string, trie

I am fairly new to Programming world. I am trying to create a common regex that would match only list of strings given, nothing more than that.

For Eg., given the below list

```
List = ['starguide,'snoreguide','snoraguide','smarguides']
```

It should create a regex like this - `s(((tar|nor(e|a))(guide))|marguides)`

I implemented a trie. Could only manage to get `s(marguides|nor(aguide|eguide)|targuide)`

I want my regex to be shortened (common suffixes tied together). Is there any better way to shorten the regex I am getting from the trie?

Comment: Easy peasy 'l'.join(mylist) in python

Comment: See automata minimizatio n algorithms

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970) has all the details and code you need. Copy/paste.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I tried implementing your code, but it gives `s(marguides|nor(aguide|eguide)|targuide)` .

Comment: Do you aim at shorter regex or faster

Comment: For shorter read about nd automata minimization

Comment: Which is hard problem and regex engine still is likely to determinize the underlying state machine / acceptor internally https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31630/how-can-one-actually-minimize-a-regular-expression

Comment: Dsm minization method will give reex you want

Comment: Please open the question, it is seem not be about the performance, addressed by a previous topic, but minimizing regex itself

Comment: Try https://github.com/siddharthasahu/automata-from-regex to build min deterministic state machine/automaton, then build optimized regex with then build optimized regex with https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions

Comment: above will produce your expected output ( though in general case, non-determinist automata could yield shorter regex)

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807365/find-simplest-regular-expression-matching-all-given-strings

Comment: @Serge Thankyou for the pointers! Will look into them. I reopened my question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result try use automata minimization.

For your simple example, deterministic automaton suffices.

Use github.com/siddharthasahu/automata-from-regex to build min deterministic state machine/automaton from trivial regex (enumeration of words), then transform automaton into regex (it is easy for acyclic automata, http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~dr/thdr/ www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~nam/publica/extAbsCIAA05.pdf) see also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions

In general case, non-determinist automata could yield shorter regex, yet it is a hard problem https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31630/how-can-one-actually-minimize-a-regular-expression